# Five different pairs of shoes in a box

Tags: probability

Five pairs of different kinds of shoes are kept in a box. Two shoes are drawn out at random.

1. Find the probability that both the shoes are right legs.
2. One shoe is left and the other is right leg.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @narasimham Originally there were $3$ questions. In your edit the third lacks.

Comment: @drhab "Different kinds" includes a host of things. The color,owner,shoe store purchased , design of strapping, design of openness, being laced or fully covered or what have you..Different "person" is already among such subset choices.However a "pair" is uniquely mentioned *a priori*.

Comment: Text doesn't need to be $\LaTeX$'ed now, it is just fine as it is now. Also, not only moderators can edit your text, if you have less than 2k reputation your edit needs to be peer reviewed and if you have at least 2k reputation you can edit questions everywhere. What I see is still a bit missing are your thoughts on the problem. How do you think to solve this problem? Were have you thought of? Which theorems/lemmas/formulas do you know but maybe don't see how to apply them. If you give this information, we can give you useful hints. :)

Comment: @santa The next time you post a question also post what you have tried and the extent to which you reached in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Number of ways in which $2$ shoes can be drawn at random = $\binom{10}{2}$

**Step 2:** Number of ways in which both the shoes drawn are of right leg = $\binom{5}{2}$

**Step 3:** Number of ways in which one shoe is of left leg and the other is of right leg = $\binom{5}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1}$

1. Probability that both shoes are of right legs = $\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{2}{9}$
2. Probability that one shoe is left and the other is of right leg = $\frac{\binom{5}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{5}{9}$

Comment: Not leaving very much for OP to do.

Comment: Looked like a starter so posted answer in detail. Else would have posted this way : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223758/what-is-the-probability-that-the-digit-0-will-appear-at-least-once-and-the-dig/1223763#1223763