# What is the probability that the digit $0$ will appear at least once and the digit $2$ will appear at least once?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Choosing a 6 digit random number, what is the probability that the digit $0$ will appear at least once and the digit $2$ will appear at least once?

Using complement, we have the digits two or zero won't appear at all:

Zero will not appear at all: $9^6$

Two will not appear at all: $8\cdot9^5$

Finally, the general case minus the sum of the above two yields a negative number:

$9\cdot10^5-(9^6+8\cdot9^5)=-103833$

But I don't see where's my error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting numbers where zero and two don't appear twice when summing $9^6$ and $8\cdot 9^5$. To fix this, count the numbers without both, those are $8^6$. Hence, [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) yields
$$
9\cdot 10^5 - (9^6 + 8\cdot 9^5) + 8^6 = 158311.
$$

The main idea here is that for two sets $A$ and $B$ we have $\left|A\cup B\right| = \left|A\right|+\left|B\right|-\left|A\cap B\right|$. Here $A$ consists of numbers with no $0$-digit and $B$ consists of numbers with no $2$-digit.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of inclusion exclusion, thanks.

Comment: BTW why do you call it "don't appear twice"? the counting of $9^6$ in my question is zero not appearing at all...

Comment: @kuhaku read "you are counting (numbers where zero and two don't appear) twice". Sorry, that sentence was ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Clue : There will cases of overlap between $9^6$ and $8.9^5$. So you have to add back the cases where both $0$ and $2$ do not appear.